# FCN with patches creates boundary

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a Unet model to do per pixel regression predictions on images. To do this, I separate my large image (1000x1000) to 200x200 pixel squares. Then use that to train an FCN model with a linear final layer. The loss function is MSE loss. In the prediction stage, I extract the same boxes but stitch it together and obtain a final output image. When I do that, the problem I am getting is that there is discontinuities between the boundary of boxes. (I can clearly see the boxes)

I've tried to deal with this by feeding 250x250 boxes to my FCN and calculating the loss for the 200x200 centre region. I do the same process for the prediction state. Extract 250x250 patches crop the 200x200 centre region and stitch the image back together. Please see some code below:

Loss Function:

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=LR)
for inputs, labels in train_loader:
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(inputs)
    output = output.squeeze()
     _, dimx, dimy = output.shape
     loss = criterion(output[:,25:dimx-25, 25:dimy-25], labels[:,25:dimx-25, 25:dimy-25])
     loss.backward()
     optimizer.step()
```

My code for predictions is as follows:

```
pred = np.zeros((height, width))
for i in range(25, height, 200):
    for j in range(25, width, 200):
        patch = img[:, i-25:i+225, j-25:j+225]
        patch = torch.from_numpy(patch)
        patch = patch.unsqueeze(dim=0).to(device)
        out = model(patch)
        out = out[0,0,25:225, 25:225]
        pred[i:i+200, j:j+200] = out.cpu().numpy()
```

I'm not sure if my problem makes complete sense. I can provide more clarification if necessary but I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to have discontinuity near the boundary because there is no requirement for the network to have smooth predictions across boxes during the training.

I assume you have limited GPU memory, so you take only 200x200 pixels as input at a time; Thus, I would suggest the following two possible workarounds.

**First**, You could use [torchvision.transform.RandomCrop](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop) to generate 200x200 cropped regions as inputs of the training. At the testing phase, you directly **input the whole image to do the prediction**. The intuition is that the model can see the full resolution of images, which is the same as testing data, while consuming fewer GPU memory during the training. In this case, you would also expect that the model needs more time to learn all training data patterns because it only sees partial data at a time.

**Second**, You could simply downsample training data, say 0.5x, and keep the output size, i.e. 1x. For example, in your case, after downsampling the input image to 200x200, the model takes it to predict 1000x1000 pixel level labels (you could use bilinear upsampling or deconv layers). This workaround method has been used in some segmentation implementations ([AdaptSeg](https://github.com/wasidennis/AdaptSegNet/blob/master/train_gta2cityscapes_multi.py#L319), [DISE](https://github.com/a514514772/DISE-Domain-Invariant-Structure-Extraction/blob/master/train_dise_gta2city.py#L354)).

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting I realized that I had this problem because I was performing batch normalization between each convolutional layer. Removing that step solved the discontinuity problem.